# Can I detect a GoogleMap camera change during gesture

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm using a GoogleMap in my app and I need to manipulate other views according to when the map moves. From what I can tell, the OnCameraChangedListener only activates when the user is finished positioning the map. I need to detect motion while its occurring, not just when it's done. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `MapFragment` or `MapView` in a class extending `FrameLayout` and override [`dispatchTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) to know when user interacts with the map in any way.

If you want to synchronize position of `View`s in your process with what Google Play services draws in its own process, I suggest first trying scrolling only. It will be laggy and won't bring any good UX. Anyway, flinging you can handle with a repeated (every 16ms or so) message to `Handler` from when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP happens to when you get a call to `onCameraChange`.

Comment: This works for scrolling, but what about flinging? That has motion without the user ever touching it.

Comment: Can I just disable the fling on the map itself?

Comment: @KairisCharm I don't think so. You may try with disabling all gestures and calling `moveCamera` when getting `MotionEvent`s.